# Reference an object on an attribute other the id

Tags: spring, jpa

I have the class Structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "structure")

public class Structure {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_structure", unique = true)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "code_structure")
private String codeStructure;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "code_structure_mere")
private Structure parentStructure;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentStructure")
private List<Structure> sousStructures;

....
```

for the parentStructure: mapped by `code_structure_mere`
    in db this field contains the `code_structure` of the parent structure and not its id.

I have the interface StructureRepository from which I wanan retrieve all the structures that I have. I get an error executing:
`structureRepository.findAll()` :

```
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22003
Mauvaise valeur pour le type long : 09N008000
```

Can I use another field other than the id to set the parent structure?

Comment: try to add (columnDefinition = "text")

Answer (score 0):

If your `@JoinColumn(name = "code_structure_mere")` reference the column *code_structure_mere*, isn't

```
@Column(name = "code_structure")
private String codeStructure;
```

should be

```
@Column(name = "code_structure_mere")
private String codeStructure;
```

Anyway, I found a [blog post](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-manytoone-association-using-a-non-primary-key-column/) that can help you I think.